# How to add images in res folder in android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add some images to res folder in my android 4.2.2 application. The problem is the project runs fine until whenever I do add, upon running it gives an error

```
R cannot be resolved to a variable
```

in the `src/MainActiviy.java` and the `R.java` file deletes it self from the `gen` folder.

Now I'm naming the folder `drawable-mdp` and every `png` image is also lower cased. But it doesn't seem to bother.
Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't that be **drawable-mdpi**?

Comment: You should put the images under drawable-mdpi

Comment: @matiash I tried that too but it didn't work Ctrl+C and then paste it in drawable-mdpi.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because `R.java` failed to create. This happens when you try to a non-png image or the name of image contains some special character or characters in uppercase.

Comment: Probably should've mentioned this earlier my image file only contains alphabets numbers and (-) and (_) and as I mentioned earlier it is in .png format.

Comment: @Abbas you can't use `_` in the filename

Comment: @Math why do you say the underscore is not allowed? I use it and I don't have any problems

Comment: @schopy as far as I remember it wasn't, I can't test right now, but if you can confirm it is allowed my bad so..

Comment: @Aashish Ok I tried that too but it still doesn't work also I changed the folder to drawable-mdpi

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys I did try a few things and I finally got it. You can't use `-` hyphen while naming the image files themselves however `_` underscore can be used.
Note you always have to use drawable- while naming the folder can't use `_` underscore